# Handling checkboxes in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been working with jQuery in past now I switched to `Vuejs`. I am unable to find a solution to these problems in `Vuejs`, I am newbie to `vuejs`.

1. I had a range of checkboxes in a table. and I have added a snippet to select multiple checkboxes with `shift + click`. This way I was able to select many checkboxes at once..

   ```
   $chkboxes = $('.chkbox')
   lastChecked = null
   $chkboxes.click (e) ->

   if !lastChecked
       lastChecked = this
       return

   if e.shiftKey
       start = $chkboxes.index(this)
       end = $chkboxes.index(lastChecked)
       $chkboxes.slice(Math.min(start, end), Math.max(start, end) + 1).prop 'checked', lastChecked.checked
       lastChecked = this
       return
   ```
2. on Click I can get the values from checkbox which I have added as data attrs

   ```
   $("#cameras_datatables tbody input[type='checkbox']:checked").each (index, control) ->
     camera_id = $(control).attr("data-val-id")
     api_id = $(control).attr("data-val-api-id")
     api_key = $(control).attr("data-val-api_key")
     row = $(this).parents('tr')
   ```

Now I have a button such as

```
<button v-on:click="onModifyClick" class="clear-btn-f" id="btn-modify">Modify</button>
```

and in methods

```
  onModifyClick () {
    console.log("testing");
    this.$notify({
      group: "admins",
      title: "Please",
      type: "error",
      text: "At least select one user!",
    });
  }
```

on Modify Click I want to get all those checkboxes which are checked on page.. and then I want to get the values which I have been added as attrs

```
<input type="checkbox" data-val="11172" data-val-username="junaid@evercam.io" data-val-api-id="dddd" data-val-api_key="dddd">
```

I want to loop through all checked checkboxes and get those data attrs,

This is more like an Informatory question because I have searched but cannot find any solutions about this.

UPDATE:

I am using Vuetable, And I am getting all those values through Vuetable loading in a callback `formatter`

```
export default [
  {
    title: ``,
    formatter: (value) => {
      return "<input type='checkbox' data-val='" + value.id + "' data-val-username='" + value.username +  "' data-val-api-id='" + value.api_id + "' data-val-api_key='" + value.api_key + "'>";
    },
    titleClass: "user-checkbox"
  }
]
```

Now, I see no way. to do what you are suggesting putting that into data and let Vue attach it to dom through the template. whereas the data is already getting bind to Dom through Vuetable.

After that I only have this

[image]

Comment: thats nice when you cannot answer just give it a -1 :) my questions are valid. do anyone know how you can select multiple checkboxes?

Answer (score 3):

As is very common for new SPA framework users, you're doing this exactly backwards.  You'll need to get out of the habit of touching the DOM directly when using Vue -- instead of thinking in terms of "I have these checkboxes, I need to read the values from them" it should be "I have these state variables in my component, and vue will automatically reflect those values inside the DOM."  Manipulate the component `data` and let Vue worry about the DOM.

So, for example, instead of using jQuery to search the DOM for checkbox elements and read from / write to their attributes, use Vue to store those values and let its template draw them into the DOM, as in this simplified example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myCheckboxes: [{
        val: 11172,
        username: 'junaid@evercam.io',
        apiId: 'dddd',
        apiKey: 'xxxx',
        checked: false
      },
      {
        val: 123,
        username: 'foo@example.com',
        apiId: 'dddd',
        apiKey: 'xxxx',
        checked: true
      },
      {
        val: 456,
        username: 'bar@example.com',
        apiId: 'dddd',
        apiKey: 'xxxx',
        checked: true
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    onModifyClick() {
      // Examine the data, not the DOM:
      var ret = this.myCheckboxes.map(x => {
        if (x.checked) return x.val
      }).filter(x => {return x})
      console.log("Values of checked items: ", ret)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="box in myCheckboxes">
    <input @change="onModifyClick()" type="checkbox" v-model="box.checked" :data-val="box.val" :data-val-username="box.username" :data-val-api-id="box.apiId" :data-val-api_key="box.apiKey"> {{box.username}}<br>
</template>
</div>
```

As you can see, most of what you were trying to do manually with jQuery now happens automatically -- at any time you can just check the contents of the component's `data` to see the state of the "myCheckboxes" list, you never read anything from the DOM, and you never write to the DOM directly, just change the contents of the `data` and let Vue handle the rest.

In frameworks like Vue, React, or Angular, the DOM is a side effect, not the source of truth as you're used to in jQuery code.  I'd strongly recommend *not* using jQuery alongside Vue, at least until you understand the framework well enough to know when it's safe and necessary to do so (not often).

Comment: your answer is good but there is a slight issue here. I am using `vuetable` and I am getting those values as a result of data loading in Vuetable.. and I have only one way. Put those values into Dom.. I am explaining in my question again

Comment: It looks like you're misusing vuetable's formatter; instead of using that to output an HTML string, [create a component](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2-with-laravel-5.4/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/CustomActions.vue) that renders that table cell and its necessary actions in Vue (working from the same data that you're currently feeding to the formatter).     If you need specific help with the vuetable library it might be better as a separate question.

Comment: Yeah I think I am on dead end because no one is willing to help, I posted a question about it in past no one answered not even on the repo.

Comment: I understand what you say but is there any solution for my current situation using vuejs? only? gettting that data?

Comment: Sorry, I'm sure it's not that people aren't willing to help, just that vuetable isn't afaik widely used so people may not know about it.   The example repo I linked to above looks pretty straightforward to follow along though, [this component](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2-with-laravel-5.4/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/MyVuetable.vue) shows how to use a [sub-component](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2-with-laravel-5.4/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/CustomActions.vue) cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of `getAttribute` element function, which return the value of the attribute passed as parameter, so we add method handler of  `change` event which takes the event as parameter and we could access `target` property that represents the current element (check box input) by calling the `getAttribute` method as follows:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {

  },
  methods: {
    onModifyClick(e) {
    let t=e.target;
      console.log(t.getAttribute('data-val'));
      console.log(t.getAttribute('data-val-username'));
      console.log(t.getAttribute('data-val-api-id'));
      console.log(t.getAttribute('data-val-api_key'));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <input type="checkbox" data-val="11172" data-val-username="junaid@evercam.io" data-val-api-id="dddd" data-val-api_key="dddd" @change="onModifyClick" /> 1

  <input type="checkbox" data-val="54545" data-val-username="brahim@evercam.io" data-val-api-id="eee" data-val-api_key="fdsdf" @change="onModifyClick" /> 2

</div>
```